# Pagination with Angularjs ui.bootstrap and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, pagination, firebase

have somebody an example for a pagination with angularjs and firebase without ng-table.
My problem ist $scope.data.lenght is undefined and I don't know how is promise working with firebase.

Thanks, Chris

```
function KontenView($scope, $firebase, $filter, $resource) { 

        var FBBaseRef = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/");
        var KontenRef = FBBaseRef.child("/posten/konto");
        $scope.getKonten = $firebase(KontenRef);


         $scope.currentPage = 1;
         $scope.numPerPage = 5;
         $scope.totalItems = $scope.objects.length;

        $scope.paginate = function(value) {
            var begin, end, index;
            begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;
            end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
            index = $scope.getKonten.indexOf(value);
        return (begin <= index && index < end);
        };
};
```

so my second try:

```
function KontenView($scope, $firebase, $filter, $resource) { 

        var FBBaseRef = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/");
        var KontenRef = FBBaseRef.child("/posten/konto");
        $scope.getKonten = $firebase(KontenRef);

        $scope.getKonten.$on("loaded", function(data) {
                console.log(data); // not undefined
                $scope.totalItems = data.length;

                $scope.currentPage = 1;
                $scope.numPerPage = 5;


                $scope.paginate = function(value) {
                    var begin, end, index;
                    begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;
                    end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
                    index = $scope.data.indexOf(value);
                    return (begin <= index && index < end);
                 };
        });
 };
```

The console will display the data, but data.lenght is undefined. Why???

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for $firebase:

> The service always returns an object (it will never be an array or
>   primitive). If the Firebase reference points to a primitive value, it
>   will be wrapped in an object with a key named $value containing the
>   primitive value. If the reference pointed to an array, you’ll get an
>   object with the array indices as keys. If you’d like a native array
>   ordered by priority instead, please take a look at the [orderByPriority filter](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#orderbypriority).

With this in mind, $scope.getKonten and data are both objects; objects do not have a .length property like arrays, which explains the undefined nature.